# What's wrong with this? I'm getting symbol not found

Tags: java, testing, compilation, null

This is the top four lines of the code method of a class:

This is *IN* the class 'CrudController'

```
public String create(Object entity, Class clazz, String req_id, HttpServletResponse response) throws NullPointerException {
    if (entity == null ) throw NullPointerException("ENTITY");
    else if(clazz == null) throw NullPointerException("CLAZZ");
            else if(response == null) throw NullPointerException("RESPONSE");
```

I'm getting these errors for these three lines:

```
[ERROR] /path/to/CrudController.java:[42,29] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class CrudController
[ERROR] /path/to/CrudController.java:[43,31] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class CrudController
[ERROR]/pathto/CrudController.java:[44,48] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class CrudController
```

The postion numbers (29, 31, and 48 are RIGHT at the beginning of '=='

Comment: throw new NullPointerException(str); // add new

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change all `throw NullPointerException(STRING);` to `throw new NullPointerException(STRING);`

Here you are throwing the exception. Exception is instance of corresponding Exception type class so you need to throw an instance that why `new` keyword is needed.

```
public String create(Object entity, Class clazz, String req_id, HttpServletResponse     response) throws NullPointerException {
if (entity == null ) throw new NullPointerException("ENTITY");
else if(clazz == null) throw new NullPointerException("CLAZZ");
        else if(response == null) throw new NullPointerException("RESPONSE");
```

Comment: I found it myself,also. MAN, you were FAST getting to this! Do you have some sort of RSS reader app for this thing!???

Comment: yes, thanks @Vallabh? it works. we troubleshot otjer issues past that lso, our library is working again.

Answer (score 0):

`throw NullPointerException("CLAZZ");` is not a legal statement. You must use the `new` operator to create an instance of the `NullPointerException`

e.g.

```
throw new NullPointerException(STRING);
```